# Gray marks on an acrylic tub

Tags: bathtub, acrylic, scratches

We recently had a new acrylic tub installed and the contractor put a few dings in it.  In his attempt to fix it, he was able to almost remove the scratches, but we are left with gray smudges in two places.  They do not appear to be residue and we have tried cleaning with warm water and soap, but are hesitant to try any harsher chemicals.  I reached a nice settlement with him over it, but we are trying to avoid reglazing a brand new tub.  Any idea what the marks are or if they can be removed, or spot glazed?[image]

Comment: Whew! At least we covered the "make the contractor pay for his mistake" part of the question. Have you contacted the tub manufacturer to see if they have recommendations for fixing it?

Comment: Does this match the location of the dings? It looks like perhaps he polished the dings out and went through the acrylic in doing so. At least on mine, the underside is a grey fiber-like mess.

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's going on in the photo; put a coin next to the spot so that we can get a size reference, as well as give the camera something to focus on.